# Function exact_change works with input command but not with command line input. How to fix this code?

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, pycharm

i can receive output via the input command but when i try to call the function via command prompt i get an error or no output ( exact_change(300)). can someone please help and explain what im missing?

```
def exact_change(user_total):
    if user_total > 0:
        dollars = user_total // 100
        user_total %= 100
        quarters = user_total // 25
        user_total %= 25
        dimes = user_total // 10
        user_total %= 10
        nickels = user_total // 5
        user_total %= 5
        pennies = user_total // 1
        user_total %= 1
    else:
        return user_total
    
    return dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies

if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_val = int(input())

    if input_val >= 1:
        num_dollars, num_quarters, num_dimes, num_nickels, num_pennies = exact_change(input_val)

        if num_dollars == 1:
            print(f'{num_dollars} dollar')
        elif num_dollars > 1:
            print(f'{num_dollars} dollars')

        if num_quarters == 1:
            print(f'{num_quarters} quarter')
        elif num_quarters > 1:
            print(f'{num_quarters} quarters')

        if num_dimes == 1:
            print(f'{num_dimes} dime')
        elif num_dimes > 1:
            print(f'{num_dimes} dimes')

        if num_nickels == 1:
            print(f'{num_nickels} nickel')
        elif num_nickels > 1:
            print(f'{num_nickels} nickels')

        if num_pennies == 1:
            print(f'{num_pennies} penny')
        elif num_pennies > 1:
            print(f'{num_pennies} pennies')
    else:
        print('no change')
```

this code works great until i try to call exact_change(300) from the command line.. so how do i fix this code where i can call the function with any parameter i enter into the command line?